# Should I learn pure PHP before the Django framework?

Tags: php, django, web

I've been coding with django for a few months now, and I have made good progress. But, I feel like I don't understand what's happening under the hood well enough to make the leap from beginner to advanced. For example, it's easy to manipulate the database via ORM in Django without having any knowledge of SQL. As another example, user authentication in Django almost only requires me to import a module and writing a couple of lines of code. I don't have to have any knowledge on sessions, database queries etc.

As I have done no prior web programming except Django, I was wondering if it would make sense to move to PHP (without a framework) and when I've learned the fundamental concepts of web development (cookies, sessions, SQL etc) return to Django development?

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with django. You might gain something by learning python though.

Comment: I already have a decent knowledge on Python. I was hoping that by learning php, i would gain an understanding what's happening under the hood. Like, how user authentication actually works. Reading a good PHP book would explain these details in great detail, i believe, because the level of abstraction is much lower.

Comment: I still dont understand. Django is a python framework. Why would PHP help you understand the under-the-hood working ?

Comment: because php doesn't abstract away the details? In order to do user authentication in php, i would have to do database queries, session managment etc myself.

Comment: PHP won't teach you anything useful, it itself hides all the fundamentals. And it still manages to not help you, as you noticed.

Comment: This could lead to an argument/discussion - which could be more opinion based, which is discouraged in StackOverflow. If you have the time, sure.. go ahead. But you can do the same in pure python too.

Comment: thanks. but how would you advise me to learn topics like session, cookies etc thoroughly using django? There are no django books written on the subject, but on the other hand, they are covered in great detail in every decent php book.

Comment: In PHP books the PHP way is covered.

Comment: I would recommend using a framework that does less. http://flask.pocoo.org/ would be a good one. And you can use http://www.sqlalchemy.org/ to help with your database queries. Then you can use resources and tutorials about how to implement authentication. It doesn't matter what the language is, the process is all the same (i.e. Check Session, Authenticate, Start/Update Session, Set/Update Cookie, Get User Record, and Authorize).

Comment: I had the same conflict when I started learning Django. I thought the same thing as you - that learning php might help me understand django better. I eventually opted not to do so, and instead **kept on learning django**, figuring out all the details from there. it turned out to be the right choice. In fact, I reached the point where I could look at php code and easily understand it *without ever learning php*. I strongly recommend you do the same. Just avoid GenericView, automated stuff will confuse you. Do everything yourself and learn client-side coding (CSS, jQuery, etc.) seperatly

Comment: Thank you everyone for your informative feedback. I've decided to write a python app without a framework to understand how django operates at a lower level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that wouldn't make any sense at all.

PHP is just one language for writing websites. It works in a certain way, but many of the things that you often see in PHP are not generally considered best practice. It's very unlikely to help you write a decent Python web app.

If you really want to learn how everything works, you could just as easily write a Python app using raw WSGI, or a micro-framework like Flask.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try to write a Python app without a framework, i found a good book on the subject also: Python 3 Web Programming :)

Comment: Or read Django's source. By doing that *and* trying to builid your own, you'll learn a lot about design decisions and trade-offs.